# install GLFW3 on openSuse linux through YaST

Tags: linux, installation, glfw, opensuse

I am in the process of moving my programming from mac to the linux distrubution OpenSuse Leap.

therefor i want to install the c++ libraries which i used on my mac on my new machine, this is done through *YaST* (*yet another setup tool*)'s software manager, through which i have succesfully been able to install multiple libraries.

I am having problems installing GLFW3, i would prefer to install the latest version (3.2), but at the very least the version must be greater than 3

under YaST's software manager i can however only find something named GLFW2 - however it claims to be version *2.7.6-3.2-x86_64* and to have the build time *Fri 11 Sep 2015*, and i am not sure if i should regard the fact that it is quite recently build and that the current version (3.2) is in the supposed version of this as a proof that it is indeed GLFW version 3.2 - with some backward compatibillity, or if i should regard the fact that the library is named GLFW2 as a proof that is is not GLFW3.

I have attempted to make and compile dummy programs (which are totally empty programs which tries to include GLFW3) but they fail to compile, claiming that library GLFW3 doesn't exist, but i can not know wether or not they fail because GLFW3 is not installed, or because it is installed but I don't know how to include it.

My question is therefor: if i install the library named GLFW2 through YaST, can i then safely assume that i have GLFW 3.2 installed and that i therefor only need learn to include and compile the library; if no, does that mean i can't install a version of GLFW higher than 3

Answer (score 0):

I have just the same problem today using OpenSUSE, and ended up installing `GLFW3.2` from [source](https://github.com/glfw/glfw). In order to get the `glfw` compiled from sources on OpenSUSE, I also needed to install the following dependencies (using `zypper install package_name_to_install`):
1) `libXrandr-devel`
2) `libXinerama-devel`
3) `libXcursor-devel`

After the dependencies are installed, I just followed standard `cmake` flow:
1) `git clone git@github.com:glfw/glfw.git`
2) `cd glfw && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..`
3) `make`
4) `sudo make install`